# Loop in R does not convert array values

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I typically work in Stata so I'm new to R. I try to understand how to run loops but even after reading quite a few tutorials, I get an error.

I try to run this:

```
foo = seq(0, 15000, by = 1000)
for (i in foo){
  dbuf <- ei(formula=formula,total="n",data=FILENAME_[i], erho=0.5, id="firm_unique")
}
```

I want to run the ei function for FILENAME_0, FILENAME_1000, FILENAME_2000, and so on...

However, I get:

```
Error in ei.estimate(t, x, n, id = id, data = data, Zb = Zb, Zw = Zw,  : 
  object 'SA3EU_EI_' not found
```

So the loop variable i does not properly insert one of the array values into the loop... Any idea why this happens?

Thanks much!

EDIT ADDITIONAL INFO:

FILENAME Is a CSV file that was imported as a data frame

EI is a statistical program: http://gking.harvard.edu/eiR

```
> dput(formula)
dsntpct ~ freeflt
> dput(ei)
function (formula, total = NULL, Zb = 1, Zw = 1, id = NA, data = NA, 
    erho = 0.5, esigma = 0.5, ebeta = 0.5, ealphab = NA, ealphaw = NA, 
    truth = NA, simulate = TRUE, covariate = NULL, lambda1 = 4, 
    lambda2 = 2, covariate.prior.list = NULL, tune.list = NULL, 
    start.list = NULL, sample = 1000, thin = 1, burnin = 1000, 
    verbose = 0, ret.beta = "r", ret.mcmc = TRUE, usrfun = NULL) 
{
    dv <- terms.formula(formula)[[2]]
    iv <- terms.formula(formula)[[3]]
    t <- as.character(dv)
    x <- as.character(iv)
    n <- as.character(total)
    id <- as.character(id)
    if (length(dv) == 1) {
        print("Running 2x2 ei")
        if (simulate == FALSE) {
            dbuf <- ei.estimate(t, x, n, id = id, data = data, 
                Zb = Zb, Zw = Zw, erho = erho, esigma = esigma, 
                ebeta = ebeta, ealphab = ealphab, ealphaw = ealphaw, 
                truth = truth)
            return(dbuf)
        }
        if (simulate == TRUE) {
            dbuf <- tryCatch(tryCatch(ei.estimate(t, x, n, id = id, 
                data = data, Zb = Zb, Zw = Zw, erho = erho, esigma = esigma, 
                ebeta = ebeta, ealphab = ealphab, ealphaw = ealphaw, 
                truth = truth), error = function(x) ei(t, x, 
                n, id = id, data = data, Zb = Zb, Zw = Zw, erho = 3, 
                esigma = esigma, ebeta = ebeta, ealphab = ealphab, 
                ealphaw = ealphaw, truth = truth)), error = function(x) ei.estimate(t, 
                x, n, id = id, data = data, Zb = Zb, Zw = Zw, 
                erho = 5, esigma = esigma, ebeta = ebeta, ealphab = ealphab, 
                ealphaw = ealphaw, truth = truth))
            dbuf.sim <- ei.sim(dbuf)
            return(dbuf.sim)
        }
    }
    if (length(dv) > 1) {
        print("Running eiRxC")
        dbuf <- ei.MD.bayes(formula, data = data, total = total, 
            covariate = covariate, lambda1 = lambda1, lambda2 = lambda2, 
            covariate.prior.list = covariate.prior.list, tune.list = tune.list, 
            start.list = start.list, sample = sample, thin = thin, 
            burnin = burnin, verbose = verbose, ret.beta = ret.beta, 
            ret.mcmc = ret.mcmc, usrfun = usrfun)
        dbuf$data <- data
        dbuf$total <- n
        dbuf$formula <- formula
        class(dbuf) <- "ei"
        return(dbuf)
    }
}
>
```

Comment: Please provide more details of your `FILENAME` object. Where is the function `ei` from?

Comment: Need output from: `dput(FILRNAME_)`, `dput(formula)`, `dput( ei)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
foo = seq(0, 15000, by = 1000)
dbuf= list()
for (i in foo){
   dbuf[i] <- ei(formula=formula, total="n", data=get(paste0(FILENAME_", i) ), 
                     erho=0.5, id="firm_unique")
    }
```

Two crucial things you forgot: 1) need to initialize a list to which you want to use indexed assignments and 2) to index the assignments. Otherwise you just get the last set of results from the `ei()...)`-call. The `get` function returns a named object  where the argument is a character value.